# Union columns of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table A:

```
Id
________
-1
-2
-3
```

And i have table B:

```
Id
_________
110
111
112
```

How best practice to get result table with columns from table A and table B:

```
IdA | IdB
__________
-1  | 110
-2  | 111
-3  | 112
```

Comment: Why do you want to pair unrelated data?

Comment: Add values 109 and 113 to table B and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: On a first glance this task doesn't make much sense. As jarlh said, the data in the tables seems completely unrelated. What makes you combine ID -1 with ID 110? What rule applies here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `row_number()`  from the data set i assumed both tables column have same number of items

```
with cte as
(select id,row_number()over(order by (select null)) rn
 from tableA
),cte1 as
( 
select id,row_number()over(order by (select null)) rn from tableB
) select cte.id,cte1.id cte join ct1 on ct1.rn=cte.rn
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use a couple of CTEs and `ROW_NUMBER`. I've **assumed** that the values should be joined in descending and ascending order respectively. This means if you were to add the values `-4` and `109` respectively then `-1` and `109` would be joined, rather than `-1` and `110` (and `-4` with `112`).

```
WITH A AS(
    SELECT Id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) AS I
    FROM TableA),
B AS(
    SELECT ID
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS I
    FROM TableB)
SELECT A.ID AS IdA,
       B.ID AS IdB
FROM A
     JOIN B ON A.I = B.I;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a good working solution.

```
SELECT AA.Id AS IdA ,BB.Id As IdB  FROM 
 (SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) As row_num FROM A ) AS AA
 INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS row_num  FROM B)  AS BB
 ON AA.row_num = BB.row_num
```